# How to implement animation for character strokes like this in cocos2d?

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone, stroke

Please have a look at this:

[Animation](http://www.eon.com.hk/verysimple/template4.html)

Just click the hyperlink at the top left of the screen to select the character and it will show the animation of the strokes. I'm wondering what kind of technologies need to be used in Cocos2d-iphone to implement this kind of animation? Any sample code will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: perhaps (un)masking, if manually setup for each individual stroke. Most likely a shader.

Comment: Anybody have sample code which is similar to this? Thanks

Comment: Any suggestion? Thanks